# Apache Ignite 2.5.0 Java 10 Compatibility on Mac

Tags: java, macos, compatibility, ignite, java-10

I have setup my **JAVA_HOME** environment variable by **$HOME/.profile** this way:

**export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"**

Downloaded the release **apache-ignite-fabric-2.5.0-bin.zip**

Checking environment:

josepens-mbp:bin josepen$ echo $JAVA_HOME
**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home**

josepens-mbp:bin josepen$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java --version
**java 10.0.1 2018-04-17**
**Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)**
**Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)**

Everything seems fine, however when running bin/.ignite.sh get the following error:

josepens-mbp:bin josepen$ ./ignite.sh
**./ignite.sh, ERROR:
The version of JAVA installed in JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home is incorrect.
Please point JAVA_HOME variable to installation of JDK 1.8 or JDK 9.

You can also download latest JDK at http://java.com/download**

Is Ignite compatible with Java 10?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite did not tested against JDK 10 and there might be unknown issues. It's recommended to use JDK 1.8 or 9.

But if you want, you may hack scripts and run on 10. For example in bin/include/functions.sh line 66 add java 10: `"$JAVA" -version 2>&1 | grep -qE 'version "(1.8.*|9.*|10.*)"'` and bin/ignite.sh line 154: `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version 2>&1 | grep -qE 'java version "(9.*|10.*)"'`.

Comment: I did search the jira for a known issue and seems like somebody has already reported this... and I'm aware of ignite.sh and functions.sh hacks... and I was able to start ignite after these hacks... thanks..